# Load an image and wait for image.complete before processing data

Tags: image, base64, html5-canvas, settimeout

This seems to be a bit a of a persistent issue that I think a lot of people would like to get to the bottom of once and for all.

The problem exists in the chain of

```
image = new Image();
image.src = imagePath;
```

then a pause to wait for image.complete with something like...

```
while(HHGimg.height == 0)
```

or

```
while(!image.complete)
{
     setTimeout(function(){ foo },100);
}
```

followed by the canvas to base64 method.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');                          
canvas.width = image.width;                                         
canvas.height = image.height;                                           
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');                            
canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

The problem is the pause to ensure that the image.complete does its job and a valid object is passed to the canvas.

What is needed is a method to ensure that the pause is enough to complete without ending in a loop that stalls the script (which this "while" method seems to)

Any ideas on how to wait for a valid image before proceeding...

My entire function is as follows...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imageFetch(imgpath, imgname)                                               
{
    imgdata = "";                                       
    image = new Image();                                                        
    image.src = imgpath + imgname;;                                             
    while(image.height == 0)
    {
            setTimeout(function(){imgdata = "";},100);                                                      
    }
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');                          
    canvas.width = image.width;                                         
    canvas.height = image.height;                                           
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');                            
    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);      
    imgdata = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');                                                   
    return imgdata;                                                             
}
</script>
```

...but until the pause to ensure the image is completely loaded some of the returns are simply  "data:,"

And now over to you. Any ideas on how to beat this one?

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`image.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Creating_an_image_from_scratch)! You also need to realize that the image can be converted to a data URL only if it is from the same domain. If it isn't, you'll run into the same origin policy errors. Also, your function has to wait for `image.onload` to be able to convert the data, so you should change your function to accept a callback instead.

Your code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imageFetch(imgpath, imgname, callback)                                               
    {
    var imgdata = "",                                       
    image = new Image();                                                        
    image.src = imgpath + imgname;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');                                     
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');                            
    image.onload = function (){                          
        canvas.width = image.width;                                         
        canvas.height = image.height;     
        canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);      
        imgdata = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        callback(imgdata);
    }                          
    return;                                                          
}
</script>
```

Then run it like this:

```
imageFetch("/", "random.jpg", function (imgData){
    console.log(imgData);
    // Do whatever you want with imgData here
});
```

I've added a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZZQX/). Note that I use a base64 URL for the image there because of the same origin policy. Images hosted on the same server and port should work fine for you.

Comment: nope. tried that. the canvas width and height are not set correctly. you still get a null base64 output. I need to check the image is loaded before the canvas element is set.

Comment: Nope. the image.onload does not fire. Using FF14.01 with Fbug and Safari 6.0.

Comment: @TJS101 Right, sorry. I've added a demo which should work. Check the console for the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try an image loader - here is a great [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/).

Here is the code given:

```
  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }

  window.onload = function(images) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var sources = {
      darthVader: "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg",
      yoda: "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg"
    };

    loadImages(sources, function(images) {
      context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 100, 30, 200, 137);
      context.drawImage(images.yoda, 350, 55, 93, 104);
    });
  };
```